# Ckeditor not working on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have declared in my assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/* )
```

I have also precompiled my assets for production, the heroku  logs don't give any errors and on my heroku server instead of getting cktext_area i get simple text_area

Comment: Are you getting some error in browser console? If so, can you copy it here, please?

Comment: I am not getting any error

Comment: Can you run your app in the `production` environment to try to get more information?

Comment: I did run in the production envoirment, it gives no error

Comment: Weird... is it possible to guarantee that Ckedior is imported when opening the page in Heroku? Can you show how and where are you defining the `script` in the page?

Comment: Put ckeditor folder and files inside it into the public folder. Hope it helps.